# React Native video end up white screen and app not responding

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-video, react-native-cli

I'm trying to render a video that runs in the screen whenever I open the app. I used `yarn add react-native-video` . I followed the code as in npm react-native-video and few youtube tutorials.

I expect the video will run once I open the app in loop (play/pause button is not needed) but my result is a white screen and after few minutes , I received a pop up 'app is not responding'

this is the line of my Video code:

```
<Video 
  source={require("./happy.mp4")}
  style={styles.video}
  repeat
  resizeMode="cover"
  muted
  rate={1.0}
/>
```

```
styles.video: {
  position: 'absolute',
  zindex: 0,
  top: 0,
  right: 0,
  left: 0,
  bottom: 0,
}
```

and this is my dependencies:

```
"react-native-video": "^5.1.1",
"react": "17.0.1",
"react-native": "0.64.2",
```

Comment: how did you resolve it? facing the same problem.